# what is the address family unknown1 in winsock2.h?

Tags: windows, winsock2

In the header file winsock2.h, I found an address family called *unknown1*.

What does this address family represents and what is it used for ??

Here is the source code of the header file [winsock2.h](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mingw-org-wsl/ci/4.0.0/tree/include/winsock2.h), and here is the code line that contain the constant of that address family:

```
#define AF_UNKNOWN1 20
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your copy of winsock2.h is strange, perhaps you left off the comment on purpose.  I keep old versions of SDKs around, they are an interesting archeological record of Windows development.  I can trace this one back to the WinNT version 4 SDK, released in 1996 and the first SDK version that supported Winsock v2.  It extended the address families first supported in NT 3.1 and Winsock v1.1, copy-pasting all of the added ones:

```
#define AF_VOICEVIEW    18              /* VoiceView */
#define AF_FIREFOX      19              /* Protocols from Firefox */
#define AF_UNKNOWN1     20              /* Somebody is using this! */
#define AF_BAN          21              /* Banyan */
#define AF_ATM          22              /* Native ATM Services */
#define AF_INET6        23              /* Internetwork Version 6 */
```

Still looks the same way today.  Obviously the comment is relevant, `Somebody is using this!` should have the emphasis on `Somebody`.  It is bracketed by products of companies that had pretty successful products back in the middle 90s, big enough to have a working relationship with Microsoft and get their product verified and supported by Winsock 2 and WinNT4 (Firefox was a company, not the browser btw).

So a somewhat plausible scenario is that a conflict was detect by a tester, otherwise having any idea how dirty his machine was, and filed a bug report.  If Microsoft didn't know back in 1996 then, well, nobody knows.  Time has not been kind to these companies and their products, the dominance of TCP/IP and the Dot-com bubble bust killed about all of them.  Surely the same happened to Somebody Inc :)

Comment: What do you mean by "If Microsoft didn't know back in 1996 then, well, nobody knows" ??

Comment: He means, I would guess, that when nobody at Microsoft knew back then for what the `AF_UNKNOWN1` was actually used (hence the comment "_Somebody_ is using this!", it is very unlikely somebody even knows it today - 20 years later.

Answer (score 0):

That actually is pretty self-describing: it is everything else which is not defined otherwise. E.g., `AF_UNKNOWN1` is an address family which is *none of the other, defined* address families; `PF_UNKNOWN1` is such a protocol family. For the `1` postfix I didn't find now quickly pointers, **my** *assumption* is that it has been introduced to avoid conflicts with possibly already existing `_UNKNOWN` definitions.

Comment: Or the possibility of adding additional `_UNKNOWN` definitions in the future if new families are discovered in use.